# EC2 to S3, occasionally sudden drop in transfer rates

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am transferring 1 file (100 -200MB) every minute from my ec2 instance c4.8xlarge to my s3 bucket via Curl -Xpost. 
The transfers work well almost all the time, but occasionally sudden drop is seen in the transfer rate.
Few Occasions - Transfer rate goes very low to few kbps and my transfer fails since I have a timeout set at 30 Seconds. Multiple retries do not help.
The transfer rate is again back to normal after few minutes.(5-10 minutes)

 
What could be the possible reason for this, any pointer would be helpful?

Comment: Use VPC Endpoints. Use Cloudwatch. Is anything unusual happening such as a low memory condition, CPU usage spike, etc.

Comment: @JohnHanley - No CPU usage spikes, just normal

Comment: Switch to using a VPC Endpoint so that your S3 access is via Amazon's private network and not the public Internet.

Comment: If this network issue is periodic then there is something going on with your instance such as automatic snaphots, etc. You have not provided details on the metrics for the slowdown.

Comment: @JohnHanley - If it was automatic snapshots, wouldn't it be always at the same time?

Comment: Also all my ec2's are in a VPC

Comment: S3 is not in your VPC. If you are not using a VPC endpoint, then your traffic to S3 goes out onto the public Internet.

Comment: Adding S3 VPC endpoint, how much will that help? @JohnHanley

Comment: Don't know but we you have removed one potential bottleneck.